# Activating a ServiceWorker earlier?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

Is it possible to tell the browser to start the ServiceWorker activation and installation phases earlier?

When I look at our performance in Chrome, which you can see below, the worker is loaded within the first 1.5s, but the activation takes place not before 3.3s! Is there a way to tell the browser to do the ServiceWorker installing and activation as soon as possible?

[image: When I look at our performance in Chrome,]

Here is my ServiceWorker code:

```
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  // Bypass the waiting lifecycle stage,
  // Just in case there's an older version of this SW registration.
  event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  // Take control of all pages under this SW's scope immediately,
  // Instead of waiting for reload/navigation.
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});
```

Comment: What are you doing within the install event?

Comment: I added the ServiceWorker code, but it's actually quite simple!

Comment: Is there other JS that's blocking the running of the SW?

Comment: @Ed. Why do you think that a JS in the client could block the SW?

Comment: Something is causing the gap. Your first point, at 1.5s, are you sure that's when the SW is actually loaded? Have you e.g. put a `console.log` just before/after the `navigator.serviceWorker.register` to establish that's really taking place 1.5s in?

Comment: Yes, I inserted log statements just before the register call and into the Promise, but the latter is executed much later.

Comment: Taking a step back, what's your motivation for wanting the service worker to activate earlier? Delaying even the initial service worker registration tends to be a best practice that ensures your critical resources needed for your first render aren't delayed by the service worker's `install` handler: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/registration